# Populate field from Previous VF page to Opportunity record creation standard page

Tags: visualforce

I've a one object Patient. To create patient, i've created VF page

(Account(lookup) & Region__c(picklist) are some field on this page);

now on Patient VF page i've one button "Save and Add opportunity".

when i click on "Save and Add opportunity" button the opportunity record creation standard page will open.

Now i've to auto populate two field(Account, Region__c) from previous vf page on opportunity record creation standard page. How can i do. Please Suggest.

VF page code line :

```
 <apex:commandButton value="Save And Add Opportunity" action="{!saveandCreateOppty}"/>
```

in controller i've used like:

```
public PageReference saveandCreateOppty(){
  PageReference pg = new PageReference('/006/e?retURL=/apex/ClientVisitReports_Edit_Wizard_Page2');
  pg.setRedirect(true);
  return pg;
}
```

Please suggest how to aut populate field from previous page on standard record creation page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check helpful article on [Salesforce URL Hacking to Prepopulate Fields on a Standard Page Layout](http://raydehler.com/cloud/clod/salesforce-url-hacking-to-prepopulate-fields-on-a-standard-page-layout.html) by Ray Dehler.

You need to create a URL that will be open a standard opportunity new page.

The URL will be of the form,
https://{org}/{object prepend}/e?{some ID field}={some value}&{some ID field}_lkid={some other ID field}&retURL=/{some third ID field}

Get the Salesforce Id of Account and Region__c fields and add these fields into the URL with their default values.

To get the Salesforce Id of field navigate to Setup => Create => Objects => Object Detail => Field Name, Retrieve the Id from URL

```
 public PageReference saveandCreateOppty(){
    PageReference pg = new PageReference('/006/e?retURL=%2F006%2Fo&[Account Field SF ID]=[Default Value]&[Region Field SF Id]=[Default Value]');
    pg.setRedirect(true);
    return pg;
}
```